# JavaScript Regex: Start of String AND End of String

Tags: javascript, regex

In JavaScript, I want to find all instances of text in the HTML that: 
start with (( 
and end with )).
Here is what i currently have:

```
/^\(\(([a-zA-Z0-9\s\?\&\=\#\.\_\/\-\%\\]{1,})\)\)$/;
```

But it's not working.

How would i implement this? Thanks!

Comment: _"But it's not working."_ Can you include example input string and expected result at Question? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Your current regex tests for an entire string that begins with `((` and ends with `))`, so it will fail if you're testing it on strings like `something ((hello)) other thing` because that string doesn't start/end with `((` and `))`. You haven't shown how you're using this regex, and it's not clear if that behavior is different from what you want.

Comment: Having the `^$` characters where they are means that whatever string you are searching, will only return a match if *that entire string* matches your search. eg, "^abc$" will find a match for the string "abc", but not "1abc2".

Comment: ok i get it. I wanted to achieve something like how angular does their data-binding. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try this regular expression:

```
var regExDoubleParentheses = /\(\(.*?\)\)/g;
```

You can test it out [here](http://regexr.com/).

Comment: I assume the OP is looking for "tokens".  If not, don't use `.*`, use `[^]*` instead, as that will include any CRLF in the text.